# yajra datatable on server side accessing API to laravel passport generates randomly error 401

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatable, laravel-passport, yajra-datatable

Currently I'm developing an ajax to load yajra datatables by server side in laravel 5.7 framework (env: XAMPP Apache 2.4.6 and PHP 7.3.0). If I gently perform a click each page or gently input on string search, then It's okay on its behavior while loading/processing.

However, randomly errors 401 when I rapidly click those buttons either quickly enter text in search box. I think the root cause is the multiple ajax call occurs when I did that, but not sure.
So this is my codes:

**javascript in blade.php**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tblpropinsi').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
               url: "{{ route('home.user.list') }}",
               dataType: 'json',
               type: "GET"
            },
            columns: [
                {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
                {data: 'code', name: 'code'},
                {data: 'description', name: 'description'},
            ]
        });
    });
```

controller.php

// Trial API

```
public function homeuserlist(Request $request)
{
    try {

        // API Access
        $response = $this->client->request('GET', '/api/user/list', [
            'headers' => [
                'Accept'        => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer eYjblablabla..',
            ],
            'query' => array_merge(
                            [
                                'type'      => 'table',
                                'col'    => 'id',
                                'findstr'   => '%',
                            ],
                            $request->all()    // yajra serverside query
                        ),

        ]);

    }
    catch (RequestException $e) {
        return response(['error' => 'API failed'], 401);
    }
    return json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
}
```

Need your kind help

Regards

Comment: in you catch; return response `$e->getMessage()` and see what the error message you get when you rapidly  type

Comment: Hi, I find this error :
error: "cURL error 3: <url> malformed (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)"